# How to change default url in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, routes

I have a table that shows the value from the database and I have 3 **@Html.ActionLink** like this

```
                        @Html.RouteLink("Edit", "StudentGet", new { id = item.StudentId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.StudentId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete",  new { id=item.StudentId })
```

Those are built automatically when I create the Entity Controller. When I click on those links, I get to the new URL: **Students(my controller name)/Edit/1.**  (for example).

How could I change my URL to something else like:  **stu-info/edit-info/ id=1**

In addition, here my **RouterConfig.cs**:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        } 
    }
```

and action **Edit** in **StudentsController**

```
[Route("~/stu-info/get-info/{id?}", Name = "StudentGet")]
        public ActionResult Edit(byte? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }
[Route("~/stu-info/edit-info")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "StudentId,LirstName,LastName,Age,SchoolName")] Student student)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(student);
        }
```

I have tried to change the second parameter in @Html.ActionLink, it can change the URL(I don't know how to change the Students one) but it didn't work cause maybe it didn't recognize the Edit action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to reach it is to use attribute routing

```
[Route("~/stu-info/get-info/{id?}" Name="StudentGet")]
public ActionResult Edit(byte? id)
......
  
[Route("~/stu-info/edit-info" )]
public ActionResult Edit(Student student)
.....
```

and maybe you will neee to change your action links for get  too

```
 @Html.RouteLink("Edit", "StudentGet", new { id=item.StudentId })
```

and add MapMvcAttributeRoutes to your route config

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

             routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
           ......
}
```

Comment: Is there anything else I need to do? Cause I got the error "A route named 'StudentGet' could not be found in the route collection."

Comment: @ĐạtNguyễn What version of net are you using? I updated my answer.

Comment: "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.7",

Comment: Fix registerRoutes and try again

Comment: The problem is I forgot to add:  routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); but then the next error is " The resource cannot be found." Is there something I have missed?

Comment: Can you pls  post new version of your  RegisterRoutes?

Comment: Of course, I have just edited it, StudentsController and Index.cshtml above.

Comment: @ĐạtNguyễn you put routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); in the wrong place. Place it after routes.IgnoreRoute as it is in my answer

Comment: Sry my bad, I'm really grateful for your guide.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to reach it is to use attribute routing

[Route("Login")]

public ActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl = "")